# Is it correct to say "Discuss that ..."?

Tags: grammar, noun-clause

Is the following sentence correct?

> We discussed that we wanted to work on this project.

Can "**that we wanted to work on this project**" be considered a noun clause, which functions as the object of "**discuss**", since "**discuss**" is a transitive verb?

If it's incorrect, is there a general rule of when a transitive verb can be followed by a noun clause led by "**that**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of "discussed" suggests that different opinions and ideas were raised. So it on purely semantic grounds "We discussed that we wanted to work on the project" is odd.

You might say "We discussed wanting to work on the project". Or just "We discussed working on the project".  Both of these fit with the meaning of "discuss".  Or you could say "We concluded that we wanted to work on the project".  Since "concluded" doesn't imply different ideas, but a single conclusion.

I don't see a grammatical problem with "discussed that".  However it would not be idiomatic since it would produce sentences that don't match with the meaning of "discuss".

Comment: Or "discussed the fact that..."